# Java NIO server and Python asyncore client

Tags: java, python, sockets, nio, asyncore

I have the following java NIO server and further below a python asyncore 
client. The server prints "Accepted...\n", however, the client's 
handle_connect is never called. Could someone help me with what's wrong 
with the server and help me connect to the server with the client?

Java NIO Server:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

class Server
{
    public Selector sel;
    public ServerSocketChannel ssc;
    public SocketChannel channel;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server s = new Server();
        s.openSocket(12000);
        s.run();
    }

    private void openSocket(int port) throws Exception
    {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", port);
        ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ssc.configureBlocking(false);
        ssc.socket().bind(address);
        sel = Selector.open();
        ssc.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sel.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> keys = sel.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> i = keys.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) i.next();
                i.remove();
                if (!key.isValid())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isAcceptable())
                {
                    channel = ssc.accept();
                    channel.configureBlocking(false);
                    System.out.println("Accepted...\n");
                    channel.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                }
                if (key.isReadable())
                {
                    if (channel == key.channel())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Readable\n");
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[1024]);
                        int pos = channel.read(buffer);
                        buffer.flip();
                        System.out.println(new String(buffer.array(), 0, pos));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Python asyncore client:

```
import socket
import select
import asyncore

class Connector(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.buffer = "hi"
        self.create_socket()
        self.connect((host, port))

    def handle_connect(self):
        print("[]---><---[]") # not called <------------------

    def handle_read(self):
        pass

    def writable(self):
        len(self.buffer) > 0

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        print("[]--->" + self.buffer[0:sent])
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

    def handle_close(self):
        print("[]...x...[]")
        self.close()


connector = Connector("localhost", 12000, Handler())
asyncore.loop()
```

Python normal working client:

```
# Echo client program
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 12000              # The same port as used by the server
s = None
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        print("socket")
    except OSError as msg:
        s = None
        continue
    try:
        s.connect(sa)
        print("connected")
    except OSError as msg:
        s.close()
        s = None
        continue
    break
if s is None:
    print('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)
print("Sending")
s.sendall(bytes("Hey server", "UTF-8"))
data = s.recv(1024)
#    s.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

**EDIT** Added isReadable to Java and added working normal python client.

Comment: I assume you know you need a lot more in a Java Selector loop than that, starting with doing something with the accepted `SocketChannel`.

Comment: Yep, have a working server and Java client. Python client doesn't work. Posted only necessary stuff for my problem.

Comment: Well you need to separate these. Try the Python client to an echo server (port 7). Try 'telnet' with the Java server if that works. I suggest you use `null` instead of getting the localhost in the server, so it binds to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Normal client in python works with the updated java server. Don't know whats wrong with asyncore. I am using Win 8, python 3.3.3, JRE 1.8

Comment: Yeah, your Java code looks like it is working OK as you get to "Accepted". I can't help you with the python code myself, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes in implementing one of the tedious asyncore methods:

```
def writable(self):
    len(self.buffer) > 0
```

This method returns `None` (because you forgot the `return` part of that statement).  The first mistake is that `None` has a false boolean value, so `Connector` is never considered writeable.  The second mistake is that you need to check for writeability during the attempt to establish the connection.  Since `writable` always returns false, including during the connection attempt, no progress is ever made to establish the connection.

I recommend checking out [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) instead.  It doesn't make you implement low-level buffer management yourself and connection setup code yourself and as a result actually produces more efficient code that's shorter and easier to write.

asyncore should really be considered a historical artifact and never actually used.